# ¿Cómo insertar una fecha correctamente en VB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

estoy realizando un proyecto y resulta que tengo una tabla de datos en sql que es de la siguiente forma: 
tabla de member

```
create table member( 
member_no varchar(20) not null primary key,
lastname varchar(20) not null,
firstname varchar(20) not null,
middleinitial varchar(1) not null,
)
```

tabla de adulto

```
create table adult(
member_no varchar(20) not null,
street varchar(20) not null,
city varchar(20) not null,
state1 varchar(20) not null,
zip varchar(20) not null,
phone_no varchar(20) not null,
expr_date date not null,
FOREIGN KEY (member_no) REFERENCES member(member_no)
```

)

en VB estoy realizando la interfaz gráfica para dar de alta datos, pero no sé cómo insertar **expr_date**  de la manera correcta.

Al querer escribir la fecha en el textbox para introducirla me marca el error. El constructor es de la sig forma:

```
Public Class adultofinal
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    
Button1.Click

    Dim conexion As String
    conexion = "Data Source=BRYAN-VAZQUEZ\TEW_SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LibreriaDB;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = conexion

    Dim adaptador As New SqlCommand("insert into adult values(" & membernotxt.Text & " , '" & calletxt.Text & "' , " & cptxt.Text & " , '" & ciudadtxt.Text & "' , '" & estadotxt.Text & "' , " & teltxt.Text & " ,  '" & exprtxt.Text & "')", cn)
    cn.Open()

    adaptador.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox(("Registrado exitosamente"))


    Me.Close()
    Alta_JOVEN_ADULTO.Show()

End Sub
```

End Class

¿De qué manera declaro `exprtxt.Text` para introducir la fecha a SQLServer?
Cito la falla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema que va mucho más allá del error que presentas. Tu código está totalmente abierto a inyección de SQL. SIEMPRE pero SIEMPRE debes parametrizar tus consultas para evitar estos problemas.

No tengo forma de probar esto, pero puede servir de guía. Fíjate que también asigné el tipo de dato correcto al parametro de fecha expr.

```
Public Class adultofinal
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    
Button1.Click

    Dim conexion As String
    conexion = "Data Source=BRYAN-VAZQUEZ\TEW_SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LibreriaDB;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = conexion

    Dim adaptador As New SqlCommand("insert into adult values( @memberno , @calle, @cp, @ciudad, @estado, @tel, @expr )", cn)
    adaptador.Parameters.Add("@memberno", SqlDbType.String);
    adaptador.Parameters["@memberno"].Value = membernotxt.Text;
    adaptador.Parameters.Add("@calle", SqlDbType.String);
    adaptador.Parameters["@calle"].Value = calletxt.Text;
    adaptador.Parameters.Add("@cpno", SqlDbType.String);
    adaptador.Parameters["@cp"].Value = cptxt.Text;
    adaptador.Parameters.Add("@ciudad", SqlDbType.String);
    adaptador.Parameters["@ciudad"].Value = ciudadtxt.Text;
    adaptador.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.String);
    adaptador.Parameters["@estado"].Value = estadotxt.Text;
    adaptador.Parameters.Add("@tel", SqlDbType.String);
    adaptador.Parameters["@tel"].Value = teltxt.Text;
    adaptador.Parameters.Add("@expr", SqlDbType.Date);
    adaptador.Parameters["@expr"].Value = exprtxt.Text;
    cn.Open()

    adaptador.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox(("Registrado exitosamente"))


    Me.Close()
    Alta_JOVEN_ADULTO.Show()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que cada valor que le asocies a tus columnas especificamente aquellas que son strings le hagas un replace ejemplo:

txtnombre.text.replace("'","") esto porque te pueden ingresar un dato con comilla simple y la inaercion o actualizaciom te daria error.

En lo que respecta a la fecha basta con que lo setees de la siguiente manera:

Cdate(txtfecha.text).tostring("yyyyMMdd")

Answer (score -2):

Tendrias que castear el dato tengo entendido:

```
CDate(exprtxt.Text)
```

Comment: Por mas que transforme a date la variable, al pasarla para construir el query la variable va a volver a ser string. Con lo cual esto no es lo que soluciona el problema. Gracias por el aporte. Te recomiendo que leas [answer] y de paso hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos